# How to extract line 1 to line 3 which are in the middle of the document?

Tags: python, regex

How could I extract the middle part (first line, second line, and third line) using python `re`?

```
--089e013d100acf582104f809fd8d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

first line
second line

third line

--089e013d100acf582104f809fd8d
```

the first part to read the mail box:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('mail.company.com')
pop_conn.user('user')
pop_conn.pass_('')

#newest email has the highest message number
numMessages = len(pop_conn.list()[1])

(server_msg,body,octets) = pop_conn.retr(numMessages)
```

Comment: Does your document always look exactly like this?

Comment: not really. --089e013d100acf582104f809fd8d is the boundary line to define a boundary between different content type blocks.  thank you so much for your immediate attention!

Comment: No problem :p You need to define some rules. How are these lines found by a computer? Are they always the 3rd 4th and 6th lines after a boundary? In that case I'd suggest that you don't use a regular expression and simply loop and count somehow.

Comment: Agreed. If these lines immediately follow the `Content-Type` line, with blank lines in between, you could perhaps return the first three lines that contain text.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't read the file with readlines() and just pick out the slice you want?  You could otherwise iterate over it and do a regexp test on the lines to be sure you have the "first line" and save the n lines after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are only really designed for simple (regular) patterns. Theoretically, a regular expression is a way of representing a finite state machine. Typically, they are used for things like tokenisation/lexers (spliting a program string into a sequence of tokens) or matching regular strings (e.g. roman numerals).

It looks like you are trying to parse multipart mime documents, e.g.:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="mimetest"

This part is ignored.
--mimetest
Content-Type: text/plain

Part 1
--mimetest
Content-Type: text/rtf

\rtf{\par Part 2}
--mimetest--
```

Here, you have an outer mime document with two inner mime documents. Each mime document has a header section separated by a blank line followed by the content.

The best approach is to write a parser that reads the header into a dictionary, along with the content. You can then use a regular expression to locate the boundary and extract the text between the boundaries, e.g.:

```
MIME_STATE_HEADER = 1
MIME_STATE_BODY = 2

def read_lines(text):
    if isinstance(text, list):
        return text
    return re.split(r'\r?\n', text)

def parse_mime(text):
    header_line = re.compile(r'^([A-Za-z\-]+): (.*)$')
    state = MIME_STATE_HEADER
    header = {}
    body = []
    for line in read_lines(text):
        if state == MIME_STATE_HEADER:
            if line == '':
                state = MIME_STATE_BODY
                continue
            m = header_line.match(line)
            if not m:
                raise Exception('Invalid header section: %s' % line)
            header[ m.group(1).lower() ] = m.group(2)
        elif state == MIME_STATE_BODY:
            body.append(line)
    return header, body

def mime(text):
    header, body = parse_mime(text)
    content_type = re.compile(r'multipart/.*; boundary="(.*)"')
    m = content_type.match(header['content-type'])
    if m:
        boundary = re.escape(m.group(1))
        matcher = re.compile(r'\r?\n--%s(--)?\r?\n' % boundary)
        parts = [ mime(part) for part in matcher.split('\n'.join(body))[1:-2] if part ]
        return header, parts
    return header, '\n'.join(body)
```

This code will handle various mime-based documents, but has several limitations/bugs:

1. This will not support headers that wrap, e.g.:

   ```
   Content-Type: multipart/related;
       boundary="text"
   ```
2. It does not support unquoted boundaries, e.g. `Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=text`.
3. It does not support mail archives like the Debian bugmail (e.g. that start with `From email date time`) or HTTP/SMTP identifier/status lines.

With these Python regular expressions:

- `^` matches the start of a line
- `$` matches the end of a line
- `[abc]` matches any of the characters `a`, `b`, `c` (one of)
- `[a-z]` matches any of the characters `a` through to `z`
- `\-` escapes the character `-` so it can be used in a `[]` expression
- `a+` matches one or more instances of the expression `a`
- `a*` matches zero or more instances of the expression `a`
- `.` matches any character
- `a?` optionally matches `a` (i.e. matching zero or one instances of `a`)
- `\r` matches the carriage return character
- `(a)` captures the content of the matching `a` expression in the next group -- accessed via `m.group(n)`
- anything else in the expressions above is matched as-is

`^([A-Za-z\-]+): (.*)$` matches a header entry in the MIME header such that `m.group(1)` is the header name (e.g. 'Content-Type') and `m.group(2)` is the content of that header.

`\r?\n` matches a Windows- or Linux-style line terminator (MIME documents are supposed to use '\r\n', but this can get converted to `\n` when saving the files locally).

`multipart/.*; boundary="?(.*)"?` locates the text used for the boundary in the Content-Type header entry.

`\r?\n--%s(--)?\r?\n` locates an individual boundary (where `%s` is the boundary that is 
added dynamically). NOTE: I have passed the boundary string through `re.escape` to prevent it from being exploitable (i.e. if it contains a regex such as `boundary="[a-z]"`).

Realistically, you should be using the `email` module in Python that supports parsing RFC822 (email/mime) documents. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html) for this states: "For simple, non-MIME messages the payload of this root object will likely be a string containing the text of the message. For MIME messages, the root object will return True from its is_multipart() method, and the subparts can be accessed via the get_payload() and walk() methods."

**UPDATE:** I have created a `read_lines` helper to support lists of strings (from e.g. `poplib`) and a string (from e.g. `f.read()`).

**UPDATE:** The `--%s\r?\n(.*)\r?\n--%s` matcher for boundary detection in:

```
matcher = re.compile(r'--%s\r?\n(.*)\r?\n--%s' % (boundary, boundary))
parts = [ mime(part) for part in matcher.findall(body) ]
```

has two problems:

1. it does not match over newlines (which can be solved by using `re.compile(..., re.DOTALL)`;
2. it is too greedy (it matches over multiple parts).

The latter cannot easily be solved using regular expressions. The solution is to split on the boundary string, resulting in:

```
[part0, None, part1, None, part2, ..., partN, '--', '']
```

where `part0` is the section before the first boundary. Hence `[1:-2]` is used to remove `part0` and the two end matches, and `if part` to avoid the `None` matches.

Comment: thank you for much for such a detailed tutoring! could i ask why i got the following error:   for line in newline.split(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't test the code, though, so it may contain bugs. Did you pass text to the function -- `with open(filename) as f: header, body = mime(f.read())`? NOTE: `newline.split('hello\r\nworld\ntest')` works for me in the python console.

Comment: i just read some mail from my mailbox using poplin.  then i got the body part of the mail, then pass this part to your functions.   i did not read in the outside file.

Comment: According to the python docs for `poplib`, the `body` part is a list of strings so you can do `header, body = mime('\n'.join(body))` or rework the code to avoid splitting/joining the body -- use `for line in text:` instead of `for line in newline.split(text):` and `return header, body` instead of `return header, '\n'.join(body)`.

Comment: You will also need to do: `matcher.findall('\n'.join(body))` if you are changing text to be a list of strings.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but the code says: raise('Invalid header section')
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code I would use to capture the three lines:

```
reobj = re.compile("Content-Type:.*?\n+([^\n]+)\n+([^\n]+)\n+([^\n]+)\n*")
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    line1 = match.group(1)
    line2 = match.group(2)
    line3 = match.group(3)
else:
    result = ""
```

**How does this work?**

1. We will capture each line between a set of capturing parentheses. They will be Group 1, Group 2, Group 3.
2. To get to the content we want, we match Content-Type (without capturing it) then everything up to the next series of new lines, which we match without capturing with `\n+`
3. Each line is captured with `([^\n]+)` which means "match any number of characters what are not a new line.
4. After capturing each line, we eat up any number of new lines with `\n+`. The final newline after Group 3 is optional: `\n*` (In fact the regex would work without it.)

Comment: That is just capturing 3 lines after a Content-Type header + blank line. What if there are more than three lines? What if there are header items after the Content-Type header? What if there are other parts following that one? What if there are nested multipart documents? ...

Comment: @reece You are absolutely right, this is what my solution does. I only answered the question raised by the OP, without trying to guess what other specs he might have.

Comment: The question that is being asked is how to extract the content of a multipart MIME document between two boundaries as shown in the example. That is the `--%s\r?\n(.*)--%s` part of my answer. To get the boundary, you need to parse the MIME headers of the document (not shown in the OP's example) to look for the boundary on the `content-type` header: `multipart/.*; boundary="(.*)"`.

Comment: @reece, yes, your solution is great.